# Printing Decimals as Percentages

Tags: python, python-3.10

I'm new to coding and I don't know how to translate a list of decimals into percentages using a for loop. This is what I have and this is the error I get.

> Create a list named q_growth_rates using
> list comprehension (preferred) or a for loop
> Print each growth rate as shown below using a for loop

```
q_growth_rates = []
q_growth_rates = [-0.2, -0.1, 0.0, 0.09999999999999998, 0.2]
print(q_growth_rates)
```

I get an error code that says "TypeError: unsupported format string passed to list.**format**" for the following

> You need to use f-strings for formatting
> Make sure that all decimals are aligned as shown below and there is a percent sign at the end

```
growth = [ str(round(x*100,1))+"%" for x in q_growth_rates]
print(f"{growth= :6,.2}")
```

the answer is given as the following, but I have to code the step before.

```
growth=-20.00%
growth=-10.00%
growth=  0.00%
growth= 10.00%
growth= 20.00%
```

Comment: The final `print()` statement is missing the closing quotation mark.

Comment: `print(f"{growth= :6,.2})` Not sure what's going on here. What is your desired output?

Comment: What is the error that you get? I'm guessing it says something to the effect of "unterminated string literal", and I recommend you find a good place to terminate that string literal.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp It's supposed to list growth = -20.00% for example

Comment: Actually you can just print the numbers output with %. It is way easier that way.

Comment: `print('\n'.join(f"growth={round(x*100,1):>5}%" for x in q_growth_rates))`

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
q_growth_rates = []
q_growth_rates = [-0.2, -0.1, 0.0, 0.09999999999999998, 0.2]
print(q_growth_rates)
growth = [ str(round(x*100,1))+"%" for x in q_growth_rates]
for i in growth:
    print(f"growth={i}")
```

Output:

```
[-0.2, -0.1, 0.0, 0.09999999999999998, 0.2]
growth=-20.0%
growth=-10.0%
growth=0.0%
growth=10.0%
growth=20.0%
```

You forgot the close your string on the `print` statement and you need to loop through the `growth` list to print everything in it like you specified.

Or you could try:

```
q_growth_rates = []
q_growth_rates = [-0.2, -0.1, 0.0, 0.09999999999999998, 0.2]
print(q_growth_rates)
growth = [ str(round(x*100,1))+"%" for x in q_growth_rates]
print("\n".join(f"growth={i}" for i in growth))
```

Output:

```
[-0.2, -0.1, 0.0, 0.09999999999999998, 0.2]
growth=-20.0%
growth=-10.0%
growth=0.0%
growth=10.0%
growth=20.0%
```

Answer (score -1):

You can just `print` the growth directly in the list comprehension

```
q_growth_rates = [-0.2, -0.1, 0.0, 0.09999999999999998, 0.2]


[print(f'growth = {round(x*100,1)}%') for x in q_growth_rates]
```